# Symfony existing table error when updating database

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine, migration, updates

I have the database entities in my Symfony application, I have created another table in the database and I want to download it as an entity in my program. When I execute the following line I get that there are tables that already exist.

```
php bin/console make:migration
```

How can I update the entities and create only the ones that are not there?

Comment: Please check the contents of your `migrations_versions` table. Have you ever run `doctrine:migrations:migrate` command?

Comment: if you run it when I did the migration, now I have returned to make changes and I want to be synchronized but to re-run the migration is when I do not create the file for synchronization and re-run the line that you tell me